# Prevent link popups in phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, popup, cordova

I am using the phonegap api, to create a native iPhone application. However when creating links between pages, if you hold down the links for a few seconds a popup comes up asking you if you wish to open or copy the links. I was wondering how I could disable these popups from coming up, to make the application run more smoothly etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it entirely, or only for links.
Set it in the CSS for links:

```
.class_name {
    -webkit-user-select: text;  

}
```

Or for everything:

```
.class_name {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is almost a year ago, but I thought I could share some thought.

the suggestion is a good one, but it doesn't quite work for me working with Cordova 2.2 and JQM 1.2. Tapping and holding on a button or a tab (actually a link, A element), the actionsheet still pops up from the bottom of the screen (of an iphone, let's say).

This is what that does it for me:

```
.yourclassname {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason not to use 'a' or '*' instead of '.yourclassname'? I tried using 'a' and so far have no problems, but curious to know if I'm overlooking something doing it that way.

Comment: you use a class only if you want to have complete control of using popup or not. but if you will never use it so there is no problem in using a tag directly.